# Moving data between react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to break the component on my App.js into a smaller component, that being my Sidebar.js. I took a small section of the code and put it in its own Sidebar.js file but no matter what I've tried, I cant call my function getNotesRows() from App.js without it being unable to find it or this.states.notes being undefined.
I just want it to send the code back and forth. This is a demo app, so I know it's not the most practical.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import checkMark from "./check-mark.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar.js";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notes: [],
      currentNoteIndex: 0
    };
    this.markAsRead = this.markAsRead.bind(this);
    this.selectNote = this.selectNote.bind(this);
    console.log("Test started 2.25.19 19:23");
  }
  
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/notes')
 .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
  notes => {
   this.setState({
    notes: notes,
    currentNoteIndex: 0
   })
  }
 )
 .catch(
  error => {
   console.log('Ooops!');
   console.log(error);
  }
 );
  }

  
  markAsRead() {
    this.setState(currentState => {
      let marked = {
        ...currentState.notes[currentState.currentNoteIndex],
        read: true
      };
      let notes = [...currentState.notes];
      notes[currentState.currentNoteIndex] = marked;
      return { ...currentState, notes };
    });
  }

  
  selectNote(e) {
    this.setState({ currentNoteIndex: parseInt(e.currentTarget.id, 10) });

  }

  getTotalUnread() {
    let unreadArray = this.state.notes.filter(note => {
    return note.read === false;
    })
    return unreadArray.length;
    }

    getNotesRows() {
    
      return this.props.notes.map(note => (
        <div
          key={note.subject}
          className={classNames("NotesSidebarItem", {
            selected:
              this.props.notes.indexOf(note) === this.props.currentNoteIndex
          })}
          onClick={this.selectNote}
          
          id={this.props.notes.indexOf(note)}
        >
          <h4 className="NotesSidebarItem-title">{note.subject}</h4>
          {note.read && <img alt="Check Mark" src={checkMark} />}
        </div>
      ));
    }

  // TODO this component should be broken into separate components.

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Notes Viewer Test App</h1>
          <div>
            Unread:
            <span className="App-title-unread-count">
              {this.getTotalUnread()}
            </span>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div className="Container">
        <Sidebar />
        <section className="NoteDetails">
  {this.state.notes.length > 0 && (
    <h3 className="NoteDetails-title">
      {this.state.notes[this.state.currentNoteIndex].subject}
    </h3>
  )}
  {this.state.notes.length > 0 && (
    <p className="NoteDetails-subject">
      {this.state.notes[this.state.currentNoteIndex].body}
    </p>
  )}
  {this.state.notes.length > 0 && (
    <button onClick={this.markAsRead}>Mark as read</button>
  )}
  {this.state.notes.length <= 0 && (
    <p>
    No Notes!
    </p>
  )}
</section>
</div>
</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Above is my App.js
and below is the Sidebar.js that I'm trying to create

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../App.css";
import App from "../App.js";


class Sidebar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <section className="NotesSidebar">
                <h2 className="NotesSidebar-title">Available Notes:</h2>
                <div className="NotesSidebar-list">{App.getNotesRows()}</div>
            </section>
)}}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: @a2441918 This solution worked to access the method, however I now receive an error 'Cannot read property 'notes' of undefined' on ln 69 in App.js. It seems the information in the notes object array doesnt get passed either

Comment: 'this.props.notes.map' is undefined. I accessed it within App.js and it is an object array full of data, but Sidebar.js cannot see that for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a method like that. You need to pass the method as a prop and use it in the child.

```
<Sidebar getNotesRows={this.getNotesRows} />
```

and in Sidebar use

```
<div className="NotesSidebar-list">{this.props.getNotesRows()}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sidebar, you're trying to call `getNotesRows()` from App, but Sidebar doesn't need access to app (you shouldn't have to import App in Sidebar.js). Instead, you should pass the function from App to your Sidebar component, and reference it from Sidebar's props.

In App.js, you'll need to bind `getNotesRows` and pass it to sidebar.:

```js
<Sidebar getNotesRows={ this.getNotesRows } />
```

Then in Sidebar.js, you'll need to reference `getNotesRows` in your render method:

```js
render() {
  const notes = this.props.getNotesRows();
  return (
    <section className="NotesSidebar">
      <h2 className="NotesSidebar-title">Available Notes:</h2>
      <div className="NotesSidebar-list">{ notes }</div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem here is that you are trying to use a class function as a static property, to put it simply, you have not initialized the App class when you import it into your sidebar(?), thus no static function was found on your App class so you can call *App.getNotesRows()* maybe you should re-think your components and separate them in container-components using a Composition Based Programming approach instead of OO approach.